# How can I debug a dbus `Spawn.ChildExited` dbus error?

Tags: python, d-bus

I have a python script that fails on the following line:

```
controller = bus.get_object(service_name, "/org/jackaudio/Controller")
```

The error is:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: 
    Process org.jackaudio.service exited with status 1
```

What's the best way to debug this? Do dbus services typically have any error logging?